# Minimizing a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to minimize the function $f:\{z \in \mathbb{C} : ||z|| \geq 2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ where $f(z) = ||z^3 + 2i||$. I've found out that its minimum is $6$. The deal is I don't know how to find the $z$'s such that $f(z) = 6$. Here's what I've done:

$||z^3 + 2i||^2 = \Big| \Big| ||z||^3 \text{cos}(3 \theta) + (||z||^3 \text{sin}(3 \theta) + 2)i \Big| \Big|^2 = ||z||^6 + 4||z||^3 \text{sin}(3 \theta) + 4$

$\Rightarrow ||z^3 + 2i||^2 \geq ||z||^6 - 4||z||^3 + 4$

Here's where I get lost. I simply don't know how to minimize any further in order to find $z$. I've thought of equaling the last equation to $36$ (since $6^2 = 36$ and $6$ is the minimum of $f$) but I get stuck anyways. Any aid is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $z^3$ lies outside the circle of radius $8$. Its easy to see that $z=2i$ is one such point that minimizes the distance. Also the circle $|z+2i| =6$ is internally tangent to the circle $|z|=8$ making $z=2i$ the unique point minimizing the distance

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make it rigorous, the thing is I might be using things I'm not 'supposed' to know yet. I have only one question, though. Why are we considering the circumference $||z + 2i|| = 6$ and not $||z^3 + 2i|| = 6$? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Find $z$'s  so that $z^3 = - 8 i$. Otherwise, $f(z) > 6$.

Comment: I thought of something very similar this morning, I found the three points that make f reach its minimum, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, for $\|z\|=2$,
$$
\|z^3+2i\|\ge \|z^3\|-\|2i\|=8-2=6.
$$
Next find $z$, with $\|z\|=2$, such that $z^3=-8i=8\mathrm{e}^{3\pi i/2}$, so that
$\|z^3+2i\|= \|z^3\|-\|2i\|=8-2=6$.

One such $z$ is 
$$
z=2\mathrm{e}^{\pi i/2}=2i.
$$

Comment: I found out two other points where the function reaches its minimum, one of them is the one you posted, yet I don't know if I should answer my own question, I'm relatively new to this site. Should I answer my question or just write a comment on your answer? Because it is correct yet there are two points missing. Thank you very much for your help!